# Want to write (or use an existing?) UDF to read a file with a multi-character delimiter

Tags: apache-pig, udf

I'd like to read a data file in Pig that uses a multi-character delimiter to separate fields (I've no requirement to write files this way). So my Pig Script will look something like:

```
myData = LOAD 'myFile' USING PigStorage(‘~|~’) as (col1:chararray, col2:chararray);
```

My issue is that PigStorage doesn't support multi-character delimiters.

Possible solutions are:

1. An existing UDF. Does one exist?
2. A custom UDF based on a **working** example of a UDF that reads files.

With respect to the second point, I've seen the much copied [pig.apache.org example](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/udf.html#load-store-functions), but the trouble is that this code won't compile (aside from the obvious syntax error, all the import statements are missing so I don't know which version of classes need to be imported!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how many fields to expect, you could use `org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MyRegExLoader` [1](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MyRegExLoader.java?view=markup)

But you need to write a regex that can parse the entire line, so it's not as convenient as `PigStorage`.